# Can integer promotion happen in the reverse order(eg. long int to int) in variadic functions like printf()?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
    long a = 9;
    printf("a = %d",a);//output is 9 but with a warning 'expecting long int'
}
```

Why can't long here be converted to int?

Comment: Is this C or C++?

Comment: To be honest, if I were the `long` and was told i'd be getting promoted to type `int` , i'd probably think you were taking the piss. The type can be truncated but printing with a format specifier won't cause that to happen.

Comment: Short answer: no.   Passing a `long` to `printf()` with the `%d` format gives undefined behaviour.   Part of the reason is that a `long` can potentially represent values that an `int` cannot, and `%d` tells `printf()` to ASSUME the passed value is of type `int`, rather than converting that argument to `int`.

Comment: That's more like demotion, not promotion

Comment: @CoolGuy: It's undefined behaviour, nothing else.

Comment: If you really need to use `"%d"` convert the value explicitly: `printf("a (after conversion) = %d\n", (int)a);`

Comment: @pmg: This will generate an implementtation defined result if the value is too large for an `int` (or raise a signal).

Answer (score 2):

Variadic functions in general and printf family in particular, are odd special cases. They are notorious for their non-existent type safety, so if you pass the wrong type or use the wrong format string, you invoke undefined behavior and anything can happen.

In your case, most likely `int` and `long` happen to have the same representation so the program works despite the warning.

In the case of a regular function though, there is a kind of "demotion" taking place if you pass a larger integer type to a function expecting a smaller one. When this happens, you trigger a conversion from the larger type to the smaller, which is well-defined. (The result will however be compiler-specific if you mix types of different signedness.)

Compilers tend to warn against such implicit conversions, so it is better to do the conversion explicitly with a cast.

Answer (score 1):

Because that's the way variadic functions behave in C language. `printf` is just a function from the standard library and has no special processing. It is declared as

```
int printf(const char restrict *fmt, ...);
```

And the standard (n1256 draft for C99) says (emphasize mine):

> 6.5.2.2 Function calls
> ...
>   6 If the expression that denotes the called function has a type that does not include a
>   prototype, the **integer promotions are performed on each argument**, and arguments that
>   have type **float are promoted to double**. These are called the *default argument
>   promotions*...
>   7 ... The ellipsis notation in a function prototype declarator causes
>   argument type conversion to stop after the last declared parameter. **The default argument
>   promotions are performed on trailing arguments**.

That means that on all parameters to `printf`, `float` are converted to `double` and integer promotions occur on integral arguments.

And in 6.3.1.1 Arithmetic operands / Boolean, characters, and integers

> 2 The following may be used in an expression wherever an int or unsigned int may
>   be used:
>   — An object or expression with an integer type whose integer conversion rank is less
>   than or equal to the rank of int and unsigned int.
>   — A bit-field of type _Bool, int, signed int, or unsigned int.
>   If an int can represent all values of the original type, the value is converted to an int;
>   otherwise, it is converted to an unsigned int. These are called the integer
>   promotions.48) All other types are unchanged by the integer promotions.

So as `long` has a rank greater than int, it is left unchanged by an integer promotion, and the format shall be adapted to accept a long:

```
long a = 9;
printf("a = %ld",a);
```

Comment: In this case there is no integer promotion nor default argument promotion though. The OP is passing a large integer type. And since it doesn't match the format string, the code invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: Yes @Lundin. As I mentioned above, the output appears with just a warning.

Answer (score 1):

Following passes a `long`, yet `printf()` expects an `int` due to `"%d"`.  Result: *undefined behavior* (UB).  If `int` and `long` are the same size that UB might look like everything is OK, or it may fail.  It is UB.

```
long a = 9;
printf("a = %d",a);  // UB
```

> Why can't long here be converted to int?

`long` can be converted, yet code did not direct that like the below code.

```
printf("a = %d", (int) a);  // OK
```

---

> Can integer promotion happen in the reverse order ... in variadic functions like printf()?

Integer promotions do not  happen in the reverse order unless code explicitly down-casts or assigned to a narrower type.

There are cases where demotion will *appear* to be true with `printf()`.
The below promotes `sc` to `int` as it is passed to `printf()`.  `printf()` will take that `int` and due to `"%hhd"` will convert it to `signed char` and then print that numeric value.

```
signed char sc = 1;
printf("a = %hhd", cs); // prints 1
```

The below passes `i` to `printf()` as an `int`.  `printf()` will take that `int` and due to `"%hhd"` will convert it to `signed char` and then print that numeric value.  So in this case it *looks* like `i` was demoted.

```
int i = 0x101;
printf("a = %hhd", i);  // prints 1
```